# How to create a new classes for each compilation using maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

In case of my project I need to create new classes after each compilation. For compilation I'm using maven compiler plugin 3.1. I tried to use **compilerReuseStrategy = alwaysNew** option but it didn't make any affect, it always compile only changed classes. Here is plugin declaration in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
            <compilerReuseStrategy>alwaysNew</compilerReuseStrategy>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

An I doing something wrong or that's a bug and this option really doesn't work?

Comment: whats the significance?

Comment: @SureshkumarPanneerselvan I'm using an annotation processor to generate some code. As i wrote above in case of my project this code generation affects on whole project even if some classes didn't changed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758704/fill-array-with-two-different-array-sequentially have a look  http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_autosave.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the incremental feature fo the maven-compiler-plugin you can change this behaviour by the [following configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#useIncrementalCompilation):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The [compileReuseStrategy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerReuseStrategy) in contradiction is intended to define the behaviour in relationship with multi-threaded running of the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, but with useIncrementalCompilation it still doesn't recompile whole project.

Comment: What do you mean by not compiling the whole project? Which project. Can you show the full pom file (or best and example of the code) which show the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

What about using `mvn clean install`?

Comment: Yes it will work, but I would have to do it each time when some code changed. It is very inconvenient to use, would be better if I could compile project with my IDE